# Vegan package point colour

Tags: r, plot, vegan, mds

I am using the following code for MDS plotting and I have trouble with changing the point symbol and colour using pch and col options. Here it is my code:

```
library(vegan) 
library(RColorBrewer)
xc <- cor(my.data, use  = "pairwise.complete.obs", method  = "spearman")
xc.dist <- dist(xc)
xcMDS <- monoMDS(xc.dist, k =2)
par(mar = c(5, 4, 1, 3))
plot(xcMDS, type = "n", ylim = c(-2,2), xlim = c(-2.5,2.5), las = 1, cex.axis = 0.75, xlab = "First dimension of non-metric  \n multidimensional scaling (NMDS)", ylab = "Second dimension of NMDS", xaxp=c(-2,2,4), yaxp=c(-2,2,4))
cols= "#66C2A5"
points(xcMDS, col = cols, pch = 16)
```

This is the error message:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`monoMDS` does not have `points()` method. Somebody's been too lazy to write that...

You can use

```
 points(scores(xcMDS), col = cols, pch = 16)
```

Apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thanks very much Jari Oksanen

Comment: The github repository of vegan has now `points` and `text` for `monoMDS`. Should appear in future releases of vegan.